# Past tense agreement should be kept always?

Tags: tense

1) I  **thought** that Picasso **is** an artistic symbol to human beings.

2) I **thought** that Picasso **was** an artistic symbol to human beings.

- Are both of these acceptable?
- Do they have different nuances?

Comment: In your specific example, the non-backshifted version (#1) is idiomatically *extremely* unlikely, but it doesn't seem that unreasonable in, say, *I **thought** that liquid water **is** essential to life*. Presumably there's some "principle" involved here that makes backshifting either more or less "required" in the "assertion / statement clause" following  ***I thought [that]...***, but I don't know exactly what that principle might be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Picasso *was* an artist. He isn't anymore, because he is dead. People tend not to produce much artwork once they are dead. But arguably he *is* an artistic symbol to people alive now, so you would be correct to say:

> Picasso **is** an artistic symbol.

Consider as an example:

> John *is* my father.
>   I *am* John's son.

If John died, you would likely begin to say "John *was* my father". However, you would **not** say "I *was* John's son"; you would continue to say "I *am* John's son". This illustrates how someone ceasing to be one thing does not necessarily change what they are or mean to someone else.

**However**...

In your example, you begin with "**I thought**...", which is the *past tense*. Therefore you should say:

> I **thought** that Picasso **was** an artistic symbol.

or, to change it to the present tense:

> I **think** Picasso **is** an artistic symbol.

Comment: Then how about this?

Comment: I think Picasso was an artistic symbol.

Comment: @yoonjinkim That would imply you think *now* that Picasso *was* an artistic symbol in the past (but not anymore)

Comment: If i say this, it means that he was a symbol in the past, and no more  considered as symbol? OR Using' was' instead  of 'is''doesn't necessarily imply as such?